# Why can I not get the value of tkinter variables?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add a configuration window in my coupled oscillator simulation. But when I want to get the value of tkinter variables to set up the system, I only get ''.

I tried to change the type from tk.DoubleVar() to tk.StringVar() but nothing seems to works...

Here the code for the configuration frame for one object. Then I create two of them and add them to the configuration frame.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class MassConfig(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, kwargs)
        self.grid()

        # Variables :
        self.weight = tk.StringVar()
        self.vitesse = tk.StringVar()
        self.position = tk.StringVar()

        self.lbl_weight = tk.Label(self, text='Masse :')
        self.lbl_weight.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry_weight = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.weight, width=5)
        self.entry_weight.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.lbl_vit = tk.Label(self, text='Vitesse :')
        self.lbl_vit.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
        self.entry_vit = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.vitesse, width=5)
        self.entry_vit.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.lbl_pos = tk.Label(self, text='Position :')
        self.lbl_pos.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.entry_pos = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.position, width=5)
        self.entry_pos.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Here the code of the configuration frame, which has two 'MassConfig' frame inside.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from gui.masse_config import MassConfig


class Configuration(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.grid()
        self.update()

        self.is_alive = True

        self.data = {}
        self.m1_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='Masse 1', width=200, height=200)
        self.m1_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(10, 5), pady=(10, 10))

        self.m2_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='Masse 2', width=200, height=200)
        self.m2_frame.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=(5, 10), pady=(10, 10))

        self.config_1 = MassConfig(self.m1_frame)
        self.config_2 = MassConfig(self.m2_frame)
        self.config_1.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.config_2.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.btn_validation = tk.Button(self, text='Valider', command=self.validation)
        self.btn_validation.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=(0, 10), sticky=tk.E)

        self.update()

    def validation(self):

        print(":", self.config_1.position.get())

        self.data['Mass 1'] = {}
        self.data['Mass 1']['Position'] = self.config_1.position.get()
        self.data['Mass 1']['Vitesse'] = self.config_1.vitesse.get()
        self.data['Mass 1']['Masse'] = self.config_1.weight.get()

        self.data['Mass 2'] = {}
        self.data['Mass 2']['Position'] = self.config_2.position.get()
        self.data['Mass 2']['Vitesse'] = self.config_2.vitesse.get()
        self.data['Mass 2']['Masse'] = self.config_2.weight.get()

        self.is_alive = False
        self.root.destroy()
```

I want to have the value of the tkinter variables self.weight, self.vitesse and self.position from the MassConfig class in a dictionary (self.data from Configuration class). But nothing come out, except ''.

Comment: When I use your code and do `print(self.data['Mass 1'])` in the `validation` function it prints out the values that I entered fine. What code do you run exactly when you get no values?

Comment: @fhdrsdg I use it in a 'reset' function : it creates a new window for the frame in a variable called `self.w_config` and then I called `self.w_config.data` to get the values. But I have nothing with my code even if I print `self.data` in the validation function. I am confused.